# Extreme Problem. Help Needed

Tags: virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

First off i want to apologize in advance for my lack of computer knowledge.
A virus just hit my laptop hard. I literally just ran out of my norton subscription today and my computer completely crashed. It wiped out everything on my laptop in nothing but a minute, i can't be on it for more than a couple seconds without having a million pop ups saying "your computer is in critical danger"
Can someone at least tell me what this is?

Answer (score 0):

I would run the following softwares to clean my computer: Malwarebytes, Superantispyware and Hitman Pro...all available virus-free at download.com.

A great resource for removal info is http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/

Their combofix is a very powerful tool that should be used as a last resource. It can render a computer unbootable depending on the virus type.

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/combofix/how-to-use-combofix

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I just went on my laptop in safe mode with networking but everything time i try to open an internet browser i can't because its empty. What do i do?

Comment: @Rafael Galiano See if you can get those programs off a friend's computer and put them on a flash drive. Then try to run them in safe mode. Some may need to be installed in normal mode initially.